# How to create and then select an Item from DropDown Menu(Bootstrap) without using ng-repeat of AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my programming requirement I would like to create a menu with Bootstrap, In that menu I have different dates that got dynamically generated based on the current date. then I click on the drop down menu, and select a specific date, and based on the type of date selection, I need to call specific function to do some action.

I followed given examples of angularJs, but everywhere it talks about ng-repeat way of doing things, with predefined set of items. In my example I need to create menu dynamically with some HTML as well.  I have done work as given below, and added ng-click on Drop Down Menu, but it doesn't work. I am new to AngularJs,May you please suggest how to handle this situation.

**Detailed explanation of what I have done**

I have below div to add the menu in one of the HTML SideBar :

```
<div class="ui-select ui-mini dropdown"> <a data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="daterange-listbox-placeholder" ng-click="OnClickToDateRangeListBox()">All Time</span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Last Month <span>{{CDate}}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{LDay}}</span></li>
      <li>Last 6 Months <span>{{CDate}}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{LMonth}}</span></li>
      <li>Last Year <span>{{CDate}}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{LYear}}</span></li>
      <li>All Time</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here CDate,LDay,LMonth,LYear computed programmatically from angularJs controller like as below :

```
this.getDayMonthYearBasedOnCdate = function()
     {
    
    var DayMonthYear = {};
    
    // code for date filters
    var monthNames = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = monthNames[d.getMonth()]
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    DayMonthYear.CDate  = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
    if((d.getMonth() - 1) < 0)
    {
         DayMonthYear.LDay = day + "/" + monthNames[d.getMonth()-1 + 12] + "/" + [d.getFullYear()-1];
        }
        else
        {
          DayMonthYear.LDay = day + "/" + monthNames[d.getMonth()-1] + "/" + year;
        }

        if((d.getMonth() - 6) < 0)
        {
            DayMonthYear.LMonth     = day + "/" + monthNames[d.getMonth()-6 + 12] + "/" + [d.getFullYear()-1];
        }
        else
        {
            DayMonthYear.LMonth     = day + "/" + monthNames[d.getMonth()-6] + "/" + year;
        }

        DayMonthYear.LYear  = day + "/" + month + "/" + [d.getFullYear()-1];

      return DayMonthYear;
     }
```

In my controller the code is like this :

```
DayMonthYear = ControlsService.getDayMonthYearBasedOnCdate();

$scope.CDate = DayMonthYear.CDate;
    
$scope.LDay = DayMonthYear.LDay;
    
$scope.LMonth = DayMonthYear.LMonth;
    
$scope.LYear = DayMonthYear.LYear;
```

And the menu comes like this :

[image]

But on select to specific item that ng-click(I just tried as an experiment) doesn't work, I checked other examples but those didn't help as those are different than this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can call a function on ng-click of li and can define that function inside controller by passing parameter or you can also get the $element val() on that clicked function.

You can also visit the below Link:

```
[LINK] https://plnkr.co/edit/mPfiXvN9H6oISIZ6j3Oi?p=preview
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me as described by the example.